# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Open' of object' _Recordset' failed - using Excel with ADO Connection

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I am using a macro developed by me in Excel 2013. Based on conditions (SQL) it will fetch data from an excel file and write on another Excel file. It creates 11 files (through For and Next Loop). It crates each file if it fetches records for each condition.

It is working fine mostly. A few times it is throwing the error 'Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Open' of object' _Recordset' failed'. Checked my code and unable to find any error. Till date, what I do is to close the macro and re-run and it will create files smoothly without error. Very rarely second time also it shows the same error. However, when I close and open the macro file and run, i get results without any error.

Need guidance to overcome this issue permanently. Attaching the present VBA Code and request help from experts.

The error come on this code line -   rs.Open strQuery, objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

Code -

Sub ReceivedReports(ByVal strConString As String)
Dim intA As Integer, intB As Integer, intRecCount As Double
Dim lngRecCount As Long
'Generate Despatch Pending Files
Pending_Date = Format(Date - 1, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
strRegionCode = "APRSTSKL0102KAMHMPNRUP"
intCount = Len(strRegionCode) / 2

```
For IntI = 1 To intCount
    StrRegion = Mid(strRegionCode, (IntI * 2) - 1, 2)
    If StrRegion = "01" Then
        StrRegion = "TN01"
    End If
    If StrRegion = "02" Then
        StrRegion = "TN02"
    End If

    'Set the new instance of Connection and Recordset
    Set objCon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open the Connection
    With objCon
        .ConnectionTimeout = 0
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .Open strConString
    End With

    'Set the SQL Query
    'Things to note here: Sheet1 is the name of the sheet which needs to be followed by $ in the query
    If IntI <= 7 Then
        strQuery = "Select [Region], [Branch], [Prod], [AgNo], [PartyName], [AgDate], [BizMon],  [Hub], [FileStatus], [RecdDate] from [Sheet1$] where [Region] = '" & StrRegion & "' And [FileStatus] = 'Received' Order By [RecdDate], [Branch]"
    Else
        strQuery = "Select [Region], [Branch], [Prod], [AgNo], [PartyName], [AgDate], [BizMon],  [Hub], [FileStatus], [RecdDate], [State] from [Sheet1$] where [Region] = '" & StrRegion & "' And [FileStatus] = 'Received' Order By [RecdDate], [Branch]"
    End If
    'Run the SQL query and store the result in rs variable
    If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
    rs.Open strQuery, objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    Dim counter As Integer, newWbk As Workbook
    lngRecCount = rs.RecordCount
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Set newWbk = Workbooks.Add
        'Put headers
        With newWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
            For counter = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(2, 2 + counter).Value = rs.Fields(counter).Name
            Next counter
        End With
        
        'Paste Data from RecordSet
        newWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset rs
        'save this workbook as a location
        TargetFile = "\Received Scan Pending Files As On " & " - " & Format(Pending_Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & " - " & StrRegion & ".xlsx"
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells.Font.Size = 10
            .Cells.Font.Name = "Verdana"
        End With
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 5
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 30
        newWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        newWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K").NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        newWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:XFD").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        'Put Border for Data Used Range
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)     'Blue Color
        End With
        'Update Hub Name
        If IntI >= 7 Then
            intLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For intA = 3 To intLastRow + 1
                strHubCode = ActiveSheet.Cells(intA, 9)
                For intB = LBound(StrHubData) To UBound(StrHubData)
                    If StrHubData(intB, 0) = strHubCode Then
                        strHubName = StrHubData(intB, 1)
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(intA, 9).Cells.Value = strHubName
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next intB
            Next intA
        End If
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").RowHeight = 25
        StrRep = "R"
        Call PivotTable
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.DefaultFilePath & TargetFile
        TargetFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & TargetFile
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
    rs.Close 'Close the connect
    Set rs = Nothing 'Release the variable from memory
    objCon.Close 'Close the RecordSet
    Set objCon = Nothing 'Release the variable from memory
    If lngRecCount > 0 Then
        strDataSource = "C:\Users\sram\Documents\ControlData.xlsx"
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strDataSource)
        Set sht = wbk.Sheets("EMail")
        intLastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        sht.Cells(intLastRow + 1, 2).Value = StrRegion
        sht.Cells(intLastRow + 1, 3).Value = "RAP"
        sht.Cells(intLastRow + 1, 4).Value = TargetFile
        wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    End If
Next IntI
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

When the error is caused by a condition that is outside of the VBA/Excel environment, which may be the case here, I will trap the error, wait a short time and try again.  Try replacing:

```
rs.Open strQuery, objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

with

```
Dim waitSeconds As Integer
waitSeconds = 1 'how many seconds to start waiting if there is a problem.  This will increase the after each failed attempt
On Error Resume Next 'if there is an error, just move on
Do ' a loop to try again if the recordset fails to open
    rs.Open strQuery, objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Do ' if there is no error, exit the loop
    Debug.Print "Recordset failed.  Trying again in " & waitSeconds & " seconds"
    If waitSeconds > 9 Then ' a way to give up trying if wait seconds gets to big
          Debug.Print "Hmmm.  That's too long to wait.  Giving up... "
          Stop ' halt the execution of the script
    End If
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:" & waitSeconds)) ' pause for waitseconds
    waitSeconds = waitSeconds * 1.5 ' increase the number of seconds to wait for the next time
    DoEvents ' allow the user to interrupt the loop with ctrl-break
Loop
On Error GoTo 0 ' resume normal behavior when a runtime error happens
```

I've added comments to explain what each part it doing, but if you have questions, feel free to ask in a comment.

Basically, this code tries to open the recordset.  If it succeeds (err.number=0) then we get out of the loop.  If not, we wait for waitSeconds, then we make wait seconds 50 percent larger so it will wait longer if failing on the next attempt.  Then we try again.